# Using “Show” property in Cesium to turn on and off visibility has a strange delay

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs, czml

I am loading some geometries through a datasource load promise like above:

```
Cesium.when(Cesium.CzmlDataSource.load(environment.apiBaseURL + `/geometry/all`), result => {
    this.dataSources = result;
    this.viewer.dataSources.add(this.dataSources);
});
```

and I am trying to switch their visibility with this callback above:

```
this.visibilitySubscription = this.store.visibility.subscribe(visibility=>{
        this.dataSources.show = visibility;
    });
```

but unfortunately the show/hide of the objects has a weird delay and I must scroll the mouse in order to see them hide or show

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by adding the:

```
this.viewer.scene.requestRender();
```

right after

`this.dataSources.show = visibility;`

so the final solution is:

```
this.visibilitySubscription = this.store.visibility.subscribe(visibility=>{
        this.dataSources.show = visibility;
        this.viewer.scene.requestRender();
    });
```